# How to use classes prototypes in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, prototype

I study C ++, I am also not strong in it, so do not judge strictly, played with classes, and decided to make 2 classes so that you can try their prototypes, to which I received in response, in the 1st case, not a complete description of the class, and in the second There is no access to the fields and in general to class. I watched the lesson on the OOP, and there the person worked this code, I decided to try myself what I was surprised, and I don't even know what to do who can explain why and how, I will be happy to hear. thanks in advance.

```
class human;

class apple {
   private:
    int weight;
    string color;

   public:
    apple(const int weight, const string color) {
        this->weight = weight;
        this->color = color;
    }

    friend void human::take_apple(apple& app);
};

class human {
   public:
       void take_apple(apple& app) {};
};
```

Error: Incomplete type 'human' named in nested name specifer.

```
class apple;

class human {
   public:
       void take_apple(apple& app) {
           cout << app.color << '\n';
       };
};

class apple {
   private:
    int weight;
    string color;

   public:
    apple(const int weight, const string color) {
        this->weight = weight;
        this->color = color;
    }

    friend void human::take_apple(apple& app);
};
```

Error: Member access into incomplete type 'apple'.

Comment: Use the second approach, but move the implementation of `human::take_apple` to the end of the snippet: `... class human {public: void take_apple(apple& app);}; class apple{...}; inline void human::take_apple(apple& app) { cout << app.color << '\n'; }`

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I understand what you can do through Header, but I am interested in a clean situation, it's just my interest Why is it possible to fix it.

Comment: I think I was totally confused at what you are trying to do.

Comment: @drescherjm I just want to understand why there is such a mistake, and how to fix them remain in the same main.cpp file

Comment: @DanilDanevich Did you keep the forward declaration of `apple`? My compiler doesn't complain about the snippet I suggested at all...

Comment: A note on terminology: This is called a _forward declaration_. A _prototype_ is a specific form of function declaration in C which has no relevant distinction in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before befriending a member function, there must be a declaration for that member function in the respective class(which is `human` in this case).

To **solve** this you can declare the member function before and the define it afterward the class `apple`'s definition as shown below:

```
class apple; //friend declaration for apple
class human {
   public:
       void take_apple(apple& app);//this is a declaration for the member function
};

class apple {
   private:
    int weight;
    std::string color;

   public:
    apple(const int weight, const std::string color) {
        this->weight = weight;
        this->color = color;
    }

    friend void human::take_apple(apple& app);
};
//this is the definition of the member function
void human::take_apple(apple& app) {};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HNtzpLGUU)

**Note:** In case you want to put the implementation of member function `take_apple` inside a header file make sure that you use the keyword `inline`.

Comment: It should be noted that putting this snippet in a header file used in multiple translation units linked together won't work, since this would produce multiple definitions of `human::take_apple`. To fix this the function should be made `inline` in that scenario.

Comment: Notice you have to define the whole `human` class here, which may be precisely what OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: @fabian Yes, but no such requirement was given by the OP. I have added a note at the end of my answer saying that `inline` should be used in case the implementation of the member function is inside the header file.

Comment: In case you were addressing me with that first sentence, `not a complete description of the class` seems like the statement of such a requirement to me.

Comment: Thx! Work) What about first code?

Comment: @DanilDanevich The 1st snippet doesn't work because befriending a member function requires a declaration for that member function inside the respective class(which is `human` in your case). While the 2nd snippet doesn't work because the expression `apple.color` requires the definition of class `apple`.

Comment: @AnoopRana No solutions, right? In terms of a particular bike.

Comment: @DanilDanevich The solution is the same that i gave in my answer for both of the snippets. I would also recommend learning C++ using some [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, C++ Primer by Lippman is a beginner friendly recommendation.

Comment: And for the book)